# Node Red Wemo Lookup JSON parsing error msg.payload : undefined

Tags: json, node.js, node-red

I am using the WeMo node plugin for Node Red with a WeMo switch.

Using the "WeMo Lookup" function I receive the following message payload:

> 2/8/2018, 12:30:34 PMnode: 6dece90e.84b898 WemoCheck : msg.payload :
>   Object { state: 1 }

From what I understand, I should use the JSON Function to obtain the actual value. Using the JSON function with the format option enabled I receive the following message payload:

> 2/8/2018, 12:41:11 PMnode: 5ae2b7bf.1e0e98 WemoCheck : msg.payload :
>   string[18] "{↵ "state": 1↵}"

I believe this is the desired result.

However I cannot obtain just the value using a function. I have tried the following two and both return "msg.payload : undefined"

```
var value = msg.payload[0].state;
msg.payload = value;
return msg;
```

or

```
var value = msg.payload.state;
msg.payload = value;
return msg;
```

I think I might be missing something obvious. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: In your first example, it shows the payload type as an Object, with one field called "state" and the numeric value 1. By passing that through a json node, you turned it back into the string that is shown in the second example.You must remove the json node in order to access the payload fields in your javascript function -- and since the payload is not an array, you want to use the syntax "msg.payload.state"

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the JSON node at all, the output is already a JSON object.

If you just want the payload to be 1 or 0 from the state value then your second version of your function node should work (even if it has an extra un needed step).

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.state;
return msg;
```

You shouldn't need a function node to do this, the change node will let you move values around with something like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solved the problem.

I just noticed you are the WeMo Node developer!

Thank you for developing such a useful and handy Node. I am just starting with Node Red and clearly making some silly mistakes. Hopeful soon I will be able to put your Node to good use.